# Method to Clean Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I am running a evolutionary algorithm in Java, which allow make strings with this elements:

```
X, Y, 0, max(, s(, ) and ,
```

I am trying to evolve from scratch different strings with a length previously determined, to generate this:

```
max(Y,X)=Y;max(s(Y))=0;max(0,X)=0;
```

But, in some cases I have this result:

```
max(YX,X)=YX;max(s(Y))=Y0;max(0,X)=0X;
```

To generate a syntactically valid expression, I need to clean the String, selecting only one different adjacent character in this cases:

```
max(YX,X)=YX --> max(Y,X)=X OR 
              max(Y,X)=Y OR 
              max(X,X)=Y and so on ...;
```

How can I do this? Is possible to assign a probability between the number of characters in this particular expression to be selected by chance?

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable. Use `StringBuilder` to generate your string. It allows cleaning and removal of characters before the final string is created.

Comment: But, the String is for example:
`max(YX,X)=YX;max(s(Y))=Y0;max(0,X)=0X;` and had created before the cleaning. I need to clean up after that to generate (for example):
`max(Y,X)=X;max(s(Y))=Y;max(0,X)=0;`

Answer (score 1):

You just should assign your new String to the existing variable, no need to clean it. As @Stav said, you just can not clean a String. Even if you're replacing a char in it you get a totally new String object on the output (unless you're using a StringBuilder which affords cleaning or replacing chars).
It's a bit hard to advise you something else as we haven't seen a line of our code.